# Copy multiple files in multiple folders into one

Tags: filenames, cp

How may I copy multiple files in multiple folders into one folder and change their names according to what directory they are copied from?

Initial directory hierarchy:

```
folder1/
    file1.gz
    filexyz.gz

folder2/
    file1.gz
    filexyz.gz

folder3/
    file1.gz
    filexyz.gz
```

Result:

```
folder1_file1.gz
folder2_file1.gz
folder3_file1.gz
folder1_filexyz.gz
folder2_filexyz.gz
folder3_filexyz.gz
```

Comment: Possible dupe: [Renaming files with its path name](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/137419)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple shell loop, assuming the files should be copied to the directory given by the value `$destdir`:

```sh
for pathname in */*.gz; do
    cp -i -- "$pathname" "$destdir/$( dirname -- "$pathname" )_$( basename -- "$pathname" )"
done
```

Comment: Also is it possible to keep the modified files in the same parent folders?

Comment: @user1703276 Modified files? There is no modification to the files being done here.

Comment: sorry I meant renamed files like all folder1_* in folder1.

Comment: @user1703276 I'm still not entirely sure I understand. Are you referring to my last sentence in the answer? I'm just having second thought about that particular sentence now and I think it ought to be fine with `$destdir" being any existing directory, even if it's a subdirectory in the current directory.

Comment: yes I was referring to your last comment. Yes, the initial directory should be the destination directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With prename/rename (aka Larry Wall's Perl-rename)(`rename` on Debian/Ubuntu, `prename` on RHEL/CentOS, IIRC):

In the parent of `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`:

```
rename -n s:/:_: */*
```

`-n` is the "dry run" parameter, replace by "-v" or remove if the renaming looks good.

Basically this move files from `directory/file` to `directory_file` in the current directory. If you have several folder levels and are using bash, you can use

```
shopt -s globstar   # Possibly already set, necessary for the "**"
rename -n s:/:_:g **/*
```

And this moves files from `some/path/to/file` to `some_path_to_file` in the current directory.

Comment: some explation of `s:/:_:` - https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-rename-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
DESTDIR="PATH/TO/FINAL/DESTINATION/DIRECTORY"
for DIRS in /PATH/TO/YOUR/DIRECTORIES/*/;
do
    for FLES in $DIRS*.gz;
    do
        cp $FLES $DESTDIR/$(echo $(basename $DIRS)"_"$(basename $FLES))
    done
done
```

Edit: I've bothered to add no explanations to the code because the OP hasn't bothered to show that they've attempted to solve the problem themselves (if at all). But assistance should be rendered all the same, hence my post.

Comment: Note that `$( echo $( ... ) )` is an anti-pattern that could be replaced by `$( ... )` (unless you want the result of `$( ... )` to undergo the special processing of backslashes that some implementations of `echo` performs).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  find folder[1-3] -type f -name '*.gz' | while read -r FILE; do cp "$FILE" "${FILE//\//_}"; done
```

- `folder[1-3]` source location.
- `-type f` search only for files.
- `-name '*.gz'` filename suffix with `.gz`.
- `${FILE//\//_}` replace '/' with underscore.